# Como não trazer uma determinada coluna no SQL, utilizando IF e ELSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Senhores, tenho uma tabela onde quero trazer a coluna quando o valor for nullo mas quando estiver preenchida ela não deve ser exibida, como consigo implementar essa condição no SQL ?

```sql
SELECT 
    OBS.NUOBS,
    OBS.DTOBS,
    OBS.CODUSU,
    OBS.OBS,
    OBS.PENDENTELOG,
    OBS.DTHSOBS,
    OBS.REGINC,
    OBS.DHPROXCONTATO,
    OBS.ID,
    OBS.FIMATT

FROM AD_PRONTUARIOOBS OBS

LEFT JOIN AD_PRONTUARIOATT ATT (NOLOCK) ON ATT.PEDIDOEXTERNO = OBS.PEDIDOEXTERNO
```

Hoje estou desenvolvendo a query acima, a coluna B seria referente a tabela AD_PRONTUARIOATT

Comment: Para eu responder com um exemplo na sua tabela, me diga qual o campo da tabela `AD_PRONTUARIOOBS`, que se for `NULL`, tem que trazer qual campo da `AD_PRONTUARIOATT`?

Comment: @rbz campo OBS.FIMATT.

Comment: `OBS.FIMATT` da `AD_PRONTUARIOOBS`... Mas e o da `AD_PRONTUARIOATT`?

Comment: @rbz o campo só existe na tabela AD_PRONTUARIOOBS mesmo, acabei errando na pergunta, o campo é somente dessa tabela.

Comment: Se `OBS.FIMATT` for `NULL`, então não tem o que trazer da outra tabela referenciada? kkk

Comment: Então, quando esse campo estiver preenchido ele deve ser exibido na tela, quando for null não deve ser exibido, só coloquei o campo ali para mostrar para você qual era, na outra tabela eu só vou trazer o pedido externo que ainda não inseri...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN A.campo1 IS NULL THEN B.campo1 ELSE A.campo1 END) as Resultado
FROM tabelaA A
LEFT JOIN tabelaB B ON B.id = A.idB
```

---

Também pode usar `IIF`, como dito pelo [@RobertodeCampos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330662/como-n%C3%A3o-trazer-uma-determinada-coluna-no-sql-utilizando-if-e-else/330663#comment669412_330663)

```
SELECT 
IIF(A.campo1 IS NULL, B.campo1, A.campo1) as Resultado
FROM tabelaA A
LEFT JOIN tabelaB B ON B.id = A.idB
```

Comment: Pode ser simplificado também: `IF(A.campo1 IS NULL, B.campo1, A.campo1)`, acho que fica melhor para leitura.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Boa Roberto! ^ Editado!

Comment: @RobertodeCampos aproveitando, o `IF` funciona geralmente em todos SGBDs? Não reparei nisso...

Comment: Não sei se funciona em todos, no `SQL-Server` e no `MySQL` funciona.

Comment: Atenção, não é o `IF` que funciona em consultas SQL Server, mas o `IIF`. E não é em todas as versões.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Boa João! Corrigido! ^